# Minimum s-t cut in weighted directed acyclic graphs with possibly negative weights

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, weighted-graphs

I ran into the following problem:

Given a directed acyclic graph with real-valued edge weights, and two vertices s and t, compute the minimum s-t cut.

For general graphs this is NP-hard, since one can trivially reduce max-cut to it by simply reversing the edge weights (correct me if I'm wrong).

What is the situation with DAGs? Can min-cut (or max-cut) be solved in polynomial time? Is it NP-hard and, if so, are there any known approximation algorithms?

I tried to find work on this but wasn't able to (maybe I'm just using wrong keywords in my searches), so I was hoping somebody may know (or find) something about this.

Comment: Where does the linear-programming formulation of min-cut fail here?

Comment: (using the notation from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem#Linear_program_formulation): For edges with negative weights d_{ij} can be arbitrarily large. Even if one bounds d_{ij} from above, it will always take the maximum possible value for edges with negative weights. So the solution to such a program will not always yield a valid s-t cut. I may be wrong since I'm not very experienced with such problems, if so please correct me. Basically I would like to know whether max-cut (with arbitrary weights) can be solved efficiently for DAGs or not.

Comment: To make this work, you have to change the first inequality to an equality: $d_{ij} = p_j - p_i$. I still don't see why it fails then, but maybe I'm missing something. I haven't thought about it much.

Comment: It's probably me who is missing something here. Does this guarantee that all $p_i$ take integral values? One could bound $p_i$ from above with 1, but I'm not sure whether this works or not. The problem seems to be that if this can be solved, one could reduce max-cut to it by reversing the edge weights, which should not be possible since max-cut is NP-hard. However I might be wrong here.

Comment: Is s-t max-cut NP-hard for DAGs? If the graph's not a DAG, you can't change that inequality to an equality, because you need the inequality if there are cycles. So in the general case the LP doesn't work with negative weights.

Comment: That is what I want to know (whether it is hard or not for DAGs). The solution may be trivial (well, not for me), but I wasn't able to find anything about the problem. In the meantime I experimented a little bit (formulated my problem as a LP and solved it using MATLAB) and it seems to work. In my case I have the additional constraint that after removing the cut-edges I have two "connected" DAGs (by ignoring orientations). Or formally, if $p_s = 1$ and $p_t = 0$, $p_i \geq p_j \forall (i,j) \in E$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've refined your problem some more in the comments. To be more specific, you have a DAG with all edges flowing away from the source $s$ and towards the sink $t$ (that is, all edges are on a path from $s$ to $t$). You want to find the minimum cut between two pieces of the DAG, where the first piece is connected to $s$, and the second connected to $t$. For this problem, a variation of the standard linear-programming algorithm for MIN-CUT works, even with negative edge weights.

We use the same notation as in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem#Linear_program_formulation%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B). The cost of edge $(i,j)$ is $c_{ij}$. We put a potential function $p_i$ on each node, and let $d_{ij} = p_i - p_j$. The LP is
$$ \begin{align*} \mathrm{minimize\ } & \sum_{(i,j) \in E} c_{ij} d_{ij} \\
\mathrm{subject\ to\ } & \ \ \ d_{ij} = p_i - p_j \ \ \forall (i,j) \in E \\ &\ \ \ d_{ij}  \geq 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \, \forall (i,j) \in E \\ & \ \ \  p_s\, = 1 \\ & \ \ \ p_t \, = 0  \end{align*} $$

These equations guarantee that $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$, since every vertex is on some $s$–$t$ path. Similarly, since $d_{ij} = p_i - p_j$ is non-negative, the potentials on any path from $s$ to $t$ are decreasing. We still need to show that there is an optimal solution to the LP with all $p_i$ either $0$ or $1$. This follows from the fact that the value to a solution of the LP above is the expected value of the cut $C_w$, where $w$ is chosen randomly in $[0,1]$, and where cut $C_w$ is obtained by putting all vertices $i$ with $p_i\geq w$ in the first set of vertices, and all vertices  with $p_i < w$ in the second set.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer Peter. It wasn't obvious at first sight that $0 \leq p_i leq 1$, but I think I got it. However, I have some trouble understanding the argument about the integral solution.

Comment: @George: it's the same argument that shows the regular Min-Cut LP has integral solutions. There should be a lengthier (and more comprehensible) explanation somewhere online.

Comment: Ok I will search for it. Thanks again very much for your help!